# How to generate different session ID every time an user logins

Tags: scala, session, playframework, session-cookies, playframework-2.5

I am using Play Framework 2.5 for my web application.

In my application, the server side app generates a session id and put email address int it when provided creadentioal is valid, so that the app can judge where requested user is already logined or not using the session id.

> Redirect(routes.Application.index).withSession("email" -> "xxx")

The server side app also discords session when an user logout.

> Redirect(routes.Application.index).withSession

I checked the session id. The session id is always same even after I close my browser.

1. login

   PLAY_SESSION=0b3fbd59f215c5df4dd937b508ef7cce42b65c56-email=pf%40ex
2. reload

   PLAY_SESSION=0b3fbd59f215c5df4dd937b508ef7cce42b65c56-email=pf%40ex
3. logout
4. login

   PLAY_SESSION=0b3fbd59f215c5df4dd937b508ef7cce42b65c56-email=pf%40ex
5. close the browser
6. login

   PLAY_SESSION=0b3fbd59f215c5df4dd937b508ef7cce42b65c56-email=pf%40ex

It is easy for an attcher to guess session id for each account. So I want to generate different session ID every time an account logins. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [Docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaSessionFlash)

```
By default, there is no technical timeout for the Session. It expires when the user closes the web browser.
```

I am guessing as you didn't close the browser, the session remained the same after you logged-in again.

So, during logout, you can discard the old session using `withNewSession` and during login, create a new session using `withSession`

Comment: The server side app shows a login page after I close the browser or logout (invoking withNewSession internally). So, the session ID expires for both cases. But my problem is play framework generage the same session ID every time when a session id is generated, which is "0b3fbd59f215c5df4dd937b508ef7cce42b65c56-email=pf%40ex" in my case/

Comment: @Yohei, have you figured out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of `redis`, you can generate random session id when user logs in every time.

That means that you will discard the play session instead of managing the user session using redis by youself.

Every time users login, you can generate session id for the user and restore it in redis and set the session expire time. when the request of users comes in, you can check the random session id within request.

**update**
when a user login, your back-end server can generate a randomId for the user, and put the random id into session. when the user logout, delete the random id. The code is like the following

```
class Application extends Controller {

    def login() { implicit request =>
        val canLogin: Boolean = // check the authority,such as secret code
        if (canLogin) {
            val loginRandomId = Random.alphanumeric // just an example, generate randomID as you want
            //put key-value into redis. Maybe (loginRandomId, email) is what you want, and you can also set expiredate for the key
            redis.set(loginRandomId, email)
            Redirect(routes.Application.index).withSession("email" -> loginRandomId)
        }
    }

    def index() { implicit request =>
        val sessionValue = request.session.get("email");// sessionValue is randomId
        val isExist = redis.exit(sessionValue)
        if (isExist) {
            //handle the request   
        } else {
            // did not login, return
        }
    }
    def logout() { implicit request =>
        // when logout you should delete the key in redis
        val sessionValue = request.session.get("email");
        redis.delete(sessionValue)
    }
}
```

Good luck

Comment: Can you explain more about detais? What do you put in your session id by withSession? How you verify session id is valid?

Comment: can you provide a link to the `redis` library?

Comment: @Zennichimaro   Jedis, you can get it from maven